# Error: failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: python, module, compiler-errors, repository

I am trying to use the C++ code adapted to python named pyMilne, for some work I am doing. This code can be downloaded [from this link](https://github.com/jaimedelacruz/pyMilne). I followed the steps mentioned in the link, and after copying the two files, I tried doing

```
Import MilneEddington
```

but it shows me the error

```
pyMilne.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I've searched in other posts about this problem and they say it could be something about the file not being set as an executable, so I tried using `chmod ugo+rwx pyMilne.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to give all the permissions and give the file the property of executable, and when I use `ls -l pyMilne.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` it gives the output

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 juanessao2000 juanessao2000 1014368 Jul 24 18:54 pyMilne.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

which I understand it means that everything should be working correctly, however it still gives me the same error I mentioned before. Does anyone know what could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for all the help!